# C# SQL Server CE error at parsing the query

Tags: c#, parsing

I can't seem to find my error at my code. I copy-pasted it with another one of my codes
and just change the table and column names.

It states the error at : "`int result = cma.ExecuteNonQuery();`"

```
public bool SaveCheckAmount(string id, int amount, string number, string bank)
{
  conn.Open();

  SqlCeCommand cma = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Check (transactionID,Amount,CheckNumber,Bank)VALUES(@id,@amount,@number,@bank)",conn);
  cma.Parameters.Add("@id",id);
  cma.Parameters.Add("@amount",amount);
  cma.Parameters.Add("@number",number);
  cma.Parameters.Add("@bank",bank);

  int result = cma.ExecuteNonQuery();

  if(result > 0)
  {
    conn.Close();
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    conn.Close();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception details?

Comment: is the transaction id column an auto generated column? if so then you shouldnt set it in the insert statement

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: paste the error message and stack trace

Comment: Soner- There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 13,Token in error = Check ]

Comment: Steven- Its was not auto generated

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this to

```
SqlCeCommand cma = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [Check] (transactionID,Amount,CheckNumber,Bank) VALUES (@id,@amount,@number,@bank)",conn);
```

`Check` is a reserved word in T-SQL.

See [this page on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) for a complete list.

Comment: It escapes the word, telling SQL that it should be interpreted as an identifier rather than a reserved word. This is also used when referring to entities that, for example, have spaces in the name.

Answer (score 2):

`Check` is a reserved SQL keyword, try this:

`INSERT INTO [Check]`